# how to call the function and get the result on ui using class based views IN DJANGO

Tags: python, html, django, user-interface

i am working on a django project and struggling to understand class based views.

```
class readBooks(TemplateView):
    template_name="books_read.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(readBooks, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
    def get_books(self):
        wb=books.objects.all()
        return wb
```

This is my class.
Problem is using get_books function is not callable.how am i goin to call this function.
sorry if i being too stupid asking. But i could not think of a better place than this.
I also need to understand how am i goin to use the returned result of this function in the Html file.

I am very new to django and Django tutorial is not so helpful for me.Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think your asking how to use class-based-views? If so, check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/ for examples.

Comment: hey,can you plz suggest some other tutorial like a project code example where  i can refer, because django tutorials only explains what are the things that can be used, not how to use them properly(According to me).

Answer (score 1):

You should use generic model interface of Class-Based Views

```
# Use this snippet to call Books.objects.all()
class ReadBooks(ListView):
    template_name = "books_read.html"
    model = Books

# if you want filter the Book model
class ReadBooks(ListView):
    template_name = "books_read.html"
    model = Books

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.model.objects.filter(author='someone')
```

that's the beauty of the Class-Based Views, if you just need the all records of books, the code below is enough but ig you want to more customization for the view like calling other model queries, then you should use `get_context_data`

```
class ReadBooks(ListView):
    template_name = "books_read.html"
    model = Books

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(ReadBooks, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        ctx['authors'] = Author.objects.all()
        return ctx
```

Comment: may i please know how am i goin to use the returned result of this function. Lets say i want to show the list of all the books on UI.

Comment: @User12340987 im sorry my mistake, you could use `{{ object_list }}` in your template to iterable list of books. `{% for book in object_list %}`